# Epidermal layer and muscle wall of colon?

Tags: digestive-system

First of all,I wanted to ask that whether epidermis is present in colon ? And if yes than how is muscle wall present with respect to epidermis. Can anyone give me a pic that has both the epidermis and muscle wall of colon.

Comment: Is there a source that leads you to believe there is epidermis? Do you mean epidermis as in the outer layer of skin? Or are you thinking of epithelium?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The colon is lined by epithelial cells (as are all hollow organs). These particular epithelial cells are different from epidermal cells, which are another particular type of epithelial cells found in skin.

Epithelial cells are distinguished by the way they connect with each other using tight junctions to form a permeability layer between compartments. 
[image]

In the colon, the purpose of the epithelial cells is to both to absorb water and to form a barrier between the luminal contents and the body.  They form the layer facing the lumen. The muscular layers of the colon, both the circular and the longitudinal, are further out from the lumen. You can see them in this histology slide:

[image]